# Create an undo button in my crud operations

Tags: python, django, crud

So I've created a simple crud operation, but the only difference is that when you delete data entered the deleted data gets deleted from the original data list but gets saved in a separate table which is in a different URL. Now I need to create an undo function where the user has done a mistake of deleting the content and in order to retain the content he can go to the deleted table URL and click undo.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect  
from employee.forms import EmployeeForm  
from .models import *

# Create your views here.  
def emp(request):  
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = EmployeeForm(request.POST)  
        if form.is_valid():  
            try:  
                form.save()  
                return redirect('/show')  
            except:  
                pass  
    else:  
        form = EmployeeForm()  
    return render(request,'index.html',{'form':form})  
def show(request):  
    employees = Employee.objects.all()
    return render(request,"show.html",{'employees':employees})  
def edit(request, id):  
    employee = Employee.objects.get(id=id)  
    return render(request,'edit.html', {'employee':employee})  
def update(request, id):  
    employee = Employee.objects.get(id=id)  
    form = EmployeeForm(request.POST, instance = employee)  
    if form.is_valid():  
        form.save()  
        return redirect("/show")  
    return render(request, 'edit.html', {'employee': employee})
'''
def destroy1(request,id):
    i= Employee.objects.get(id=id)

    if request.method==='POST':
        if POST.objects.filter(ename=request.POST['ename']) and POST.objects.filter(eid=request.POST['eemail']) and POST.objects.filter(econtact=request.POST['econtact']):           
            print(employee.ename,employee.eemail,employee.econtact)
            i.deleted=True
            i.save()
            return redirect("/show")
        else:
            print("Nothing here")
            return HttpResponse("Nothing")
    else:
         retrun redirect('/show/')       
'''   

def destroy(request,id):
    employee= Employee.objects.get(id=id)                                      
    x=Deleted()
    x.eid= employee.eid
    x.ename=employee.ename
    x.eemail=employee.eemail
    x.econtact=employee.econtact
    x.save()
    employee.delete()

    return redirect ('/show')


def test(request):  
    deleted = Deleted.objects.all()
    return render(request,"deleted.html",{'deleted':deleted})
```

Comment: Rather than have a separate table with the exact same fields why not just create a field called `status` and have the user change the status between deleted and not deleted?

Comment: Actually, I figured it out. I used the same code as the destroy function just switched it vice versa. like employee=Deleted.objects.get(id=id) and x =Employee().

Comment: Okay, but do you see how having two tables with the same fields is unnecessary when you could just filter the queryset? Getting active employees: `active_employees = Employee.objects.exclude(status='deleted')`, making employee active again: `deleted_employee.status = 'active'` `deleted_employee.save()`... as you can see there's way less code.